# UWP unable to play audio inside web view

Tags: webview, uwp

I've been looking for how to play audio from any website inside the webview?

I've noticed Chrome Browser playing the audio but My WebView app doesn't play. Can you please provide me any resource or code snippet?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What's the language you are using for testing? What's the version of your uwp app and windows 10 OS? I tested on my side with the [WebView official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlWebView) to navigate to a  website that can play audio , and it can play normal. If I misunderstood you please details your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am using C# language, my app version is 1.0.98.0, My windows 10 Pro version is 1703, If anything need to give permission or add reference,

Comment: Hi, its working fine now, Its problem with my PC audio driver, while plugged headset and tested, its perfectly played audio file, thanks.